# Is 'poisson-izing' a feature a useful method?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, lasso, normalization, poisson-regression

When using linear LASSO regression, it is wise to normalize the features; for example, by subtracting the sample mean of the feature and dividing by the sample standard deviation:

$$ X' = \frac{X - \bar{X}}{s}$$

where X is a column of features; $\bar{X}$ is the  mean of that column and $s$ is the standard deviation. Since the residuals are assumed to be Gaussian for linear least squares regression $X'$ is thus transformed to $X' \sim N(0,1)$.

But now lets say that we are using Poisson regression. I found out through experimentation that subtracting the mean is not useful. If we assume the residuals have a Poisson distribution, then the true mean and true variance of a feature column should be equal. Then we want $X' \sim Poiss(1)$, which is achieved by:

$$X' = \frac{X}{\bar{X}}.$$

From my perspective, this is an effective 'poissonization' for the regression analysis that I am performing; in that Poisson LASSO when features are treated with this transformation gives better results than both untransformed and normalized features.

But I'm trying to find some use of this transformation, and I don't really see it anywhere. I'd like a citation of someone using a transformation like this in literature; or else an explanation of why this is a bad idea.

Comment: "If we assume the residuals have a Poisson distribution, then the true mean and true variance of a feature column should be equal."  Using poisson regression does not imply any assumption on the distribution of the *features*, just as linear regression does not need any such assumption.  What's more important is that the features you use are linearly related to the conditional expectation of the target (on the link scale).  So this transformation may indeed be useful, but the judge of that is the performance of the model under cross validation.

Comment: What, exactly, is your motivation for doing this? Is it just to equalize the SDs of the various features so as not to bias the LASSO solution towards some features over others based on the units / scaling w/i which they happen to be coded?

Comment: $\frac{x-\bar{x}}{s}$ is not necessarily normally distributed

Comment: @gung The motivation was that it occurred to me as an idea, I tried it, and it worked better. The features are all counts, so they are in the range $[0, \infty)$. By worked better, I mean that a Poisson LASSO regression fitted using cross-validation (the way that `glmnet` optimizes $\lambda$ by cross-validation) produced a model that more accurately estimated the response variable than features normalized or not-normalized. I just experimented with this and got good results, and am trying to see if these good results are due to using a good method or though random luck.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it sounds like your method is trying to "unpoisson" the data.

You don't typically see changes-of-variable for a *regressor* along the lines of what you propose. That's for a couple reasons: 1) You don't need normally distributed regressors, you just want centered/scaled regressors so the L1-penalty is comparing apples-to-apples in terms of effect-size 2) $X/\bar{X}$ has no out of sample validity since the value of $\bar{X}$ is subjective. 3) The [variance stabilizing transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation) $\sqrt{x}$ is known to make more "normally distributed" data out of Poisson values. 4) A log transform is like a square root but has more readily available interpretation.

That said, there's no reason you can't use $\bar{X}$ as a *plug-in* estimate of the variance. However, to "center-scale" a variable means dividing by the standard error, not the variance, so I would propose the following transformation instead:

$$ X^* = \frac{X-\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\bar{X}}} $$

Alternately, you can just map the quantiles of your Poisson sample onto a standard normal quantile.

As far as evaluating your ideas, it's always good to have an approach in mind. Here's a simulation showing the rate of rejection for Shapiro-Wilk tests of $X/ \bar{X}$ versus $\sqrt{X}$ in samples of Poisson values.

```
set.seed(123)
p <- replicate(1e5, {
  x <- rpois(100, 10)
  c(
    'xbarx' = shapiro.test(x/mean(x))$p.value,
    'sqrtx'= shapiro.test(sqrt(x))$p.value
  )
})
rowMeans(p < 0.05)

> rowMeans(p < 0.05)
  xbarx   sqrtx 
0.45866 0.34166
```

You can see $\sqrt{x}$ rejects the null 34% of the time whereas $x/\bar{x}$ rejects the null 46% of the time: i.e. in a sample of 100 there is more statistical evidence to say the $X/\bar{X}$ is non-normal than the $\sqrt{X}$, putting aside some known issues with the test.

In summary $X/\bar{X}$ doesn't make the regressor more normal as you say, and normality isn't necessary to begin with.